# How can I list all users and groups in a windows domain?

Tags: windows, winapi

How can I list all users and groups of a windows domain via win32 API?

Currently I use the net.exe command but this is problematic with encoding of special characters like umlauts.

I hope that a windows API can handle unicode characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IDirectorySearch interface for both

MSDN shows you how in the following link:
Enumerating users: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676307(v=vs.85).aspx
Enumerating groups: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676301(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is via the LDAP directory. This required the known of some things about the domain.